# How do I add 3rd party widget in wix website -

Tags: api, widget, velo

I am trying to add a 3rd party custom widget on the Wix website. I have added the bellow code in the tools and analytics option of the website with the perfect **WORKING API KEY**. But I am not able to render the widget to my Wix website

```
<script src="https://bountifier.com/api.js" async="true" onload="myBounty()"></script>
<script>
   function myBounty()
    {
        var bounty = new Bountify('<api key>',function(){
            var options = {"text":"Report & Win"};
            bounty.renderButton(options);
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you placing the code before the Body - end?

Comment: yes, I have placed the code before the Body-end. @Shan